# How many servers do I need to run cardano-wallet?

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

I want to automate the sell process of NFTs. It seems to me that the only backend wallet available right now is `cardano-wallet`. To run `cardano-wallet` I need to install `cardano-node`. If you investigate about `cardano-node` you always read about stake pools which seem to need 3 servers.

If I only want to use `cardano-wallet` for the purpose mentioned above (no stake pool) do I need 3 servers too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run everything on one server. You can run cardano-node in the background and use cardano-wallet or cardano-cli from your application (just export the `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` environment variable to the node socket path).

You can run cardano-node in the background either as deamon or you can use something like docker to do it.